# Perfect square or irrational number

Tags: number-theory

If $d$ is a positive integer, then the $\sqrt{9d^4+132d^2-16}$ is an integer or an irrational number? This question appears in my attempt to prove that the only triangle with integers for sides and area in arithmetic progression has sides $(3, 4, 5)$ and area $6$.

Comment: According to Wolfy, $9d^4+132d^2-16 = 9 (d^2 + 22/3)^2 - 500$.

Comment: The square root of _any_ positive integer is either an integer or irrational.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $9d^4+132d^2-16 =(3d^2+22)^2-500$. As the next biggest square below $n^2$ that is of the same parity as $n^2$ is $(n-2)^2=n^2-4(n-4)$, we conclude that $9d^4+132d^2-16$ can at most be a square when $4(3d^2+22-1)\le 500$, i.e., $d<6$.  This leaves finitely many cases for manual checking.

Comment: That means I have to check for d=1, 2, 3, 4 or 5?

Comment: @John correct, and that's at most where it can occur.